GORM - Syntax Error near "`", but no backtick in the query using string literal
I got this code to recurse into Categories structure:
I used this query:
        err = DB.Exec(`
            WITH RECURSIVE CategoryCTE AS (
                SELECT ID, Title, Parent_id, Description, Shortcut, Icon, Public, 0 AS Depth
                FROM categories
                WHERE id IN (?)  -- Start from the specified base category IDs
            
                UNION ALL
            
                SELECT c.ID, c.Title, c.Parent_id, c.Description, c.Shortcut, c.Icon, c.Public, cte.Depth + 1 as Depth
                FROM categories c
                INNER JOIN CategoryCTE cte ON c.parent_id = cte.id
                HAVING Depth < ?  -- Limit to the specified Depth
            )
            SELECT * FROM CategoryCTE;`,
            catIDs,
            depth,
        ).Scan(&cats).Error

    var cats []MinifiedCategory

    if depth > 1 {
        // Convert catIDs to string for IN clause
        var catIDstring []string
        for _, id := range catIDs {
            catIDstring = append(catIDstring, strconv.Itoa(int(id)))
        }

        // Recursive CTE query to get subcategories, scan result to MinifiedCategory
        var query string = fmt.Sprintf(`
            WITH RECURSIVE CategoryCTE AS (
                SELECT ID, Title, Parent_id, Description, Shortcut, Icon, Public, 0 AS Depth
                FROM categories
                WHERE id IN (%s)  -- Start from the specified base category IDs
            
                UNION ALL
            
                SELECT c.ID, c.Title, c.Parent_id, c.Description, c.Shortcut, c.Icon, c.Public, cte.Depth + 1 as Depth
                FROM categories c
                INNER JOIN CategoryCTE cte ON c.parent_id = cte.id
                HAVING Depth < %d  -- Limit to the specified Depth
            )
            SELECT * FROM CategoryCTE;
        `, strings.Join(catIDstring, ","), depth)

        // Execute query and scan result to MinifiedCategory
        err = DB.Exec(query).Scan(&cats).Error

Im trying to keep it readable so I keep it in string literal. I've used exec with arguments. Now I'm trying this. Nothing works!
Everytime I get Error #01: Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;...near '(backtick)' at line 1.
I've tryied printing out and exporting into the file and see for myself there's no backtick at all in the query! But it always fails with this error.
 Error #01: Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`' at line 1

How can I use backticks for GORM query but don't get stuck in this? Or what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

When using DB.Raw instead DB.Exec it works. No idea why. Thanks

What happens if you use Raw instead of  Exec ?

when used Raw it executes properly but then it requires custom scanner which I'll play with a little. Thanks.
But why did it work?

I don't know the exact reason, but quickly looking at GORM source code, it seems that Exec and Raw don't use the same processor.

Please be ware that you have mariadb and not mysql! No, the two are not the same!

I don't know why you are using backtick, simply use double quotation
s := fmt.Sprintf("%s is %d years old.\n", name, age)


https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#example-Sprintf
